# Making synchronous ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

I am new to Ajax and jquery
I have something like this:

```
var a=0;
var resp= [ Some array ]
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
console.log(response[i])
console.log(i)   //this gets executed 10 times after which the following code executes

// make ajax call

var temp= function(){
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
//set some value
a=5;
return deferred.promise();
}
temp.done(function(){

var myvar = a + resp[i]
}

}
```

My problem is i is printed 10 times and then the codes which follows executes. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The `temp` function has no `.done` method. Did you mean `temp()`? Maybe better show us your actual code.

Comment: But notice that neither ajax nor promises will be synchronous, so maybe there's more tht is wrong.

Comment: You never said what behavior you are expecting.